# Невидимое значение у margin

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста. Откуда может взяться этот отступ. В консоле отображается как margin, но никакого значения не присвоено. 
Спасибо!

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Скорее всего это ширина элемента.

Comment: msrgin по умолчанию прописан... обнули... *{margin:0;}